# Replace a part of a Timestamps (YYYY-MM-DD) in relation to another columns YYYY-MM-DD using either node js or bigquery SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, google-bigquery

So as shown in the BigQuery table, start_date, end_date, expected_start_date, and expected_end_date are all timestamp types. I want to have the expected_start_date and expected_end_date to have the same YEARS-MONTH-DAYS (only those 3 not hours minutes seconds) as there respective start_date and end_date in the same row.

For example, that first row has a start_date of 2022-06-16 09:19:18.433729 UTC and a expected_start_date of 2022-07-08 04:00:00 UTC. I want the expected_start_date to have the same date as the start_date like this 2022-06-16 04:00:00 UTC. Is there anyway I can replace just the expected_start_date years months and days in relation to the start_dates years months and days with timestamp types using either node.js (javascript) or bigquery sql. Same thing I want to be applied to the expected_end_date and end_date.

[BigQuery table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtQh7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Extract](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#extract) function to extract date and time in BigQuery SQL.

Try the below query:

```
WITH
  temp_table AS(
  SELECT
    "2022-06-19 19:09:18.227 UTC" start_date,
    "2022-06-20 04:00:00 UTC" expected_Start_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "2022-08-19 00:29:18.227 UTC",
    "2022-08-20 05:00:00 UTC" )
SELECT
  *,
  CONCAT( EXTRACT(DATE
    FROM
      TIMESTAMP(start_date)),' ',EXTRACT(TIME
    FROM
      TIMESTAMP(expected_Start_date)) ) AS result
FROM
  temp_table;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, will this work with timestamp types?

Comment: @JoshAnderson. Yes, it will work.